# Setting text widget to one page only

Tags: plugins, widgets, pages

I've tried several methods of trying to add my text widget to only one page (my about page) and everything fails! Currently I have a plugin that lets you choose with a text box which page you want the widget to appear on... it doesn't work.

This is the page where it appears... [Home Wordpress Page](http://www.imaspy.com/wordpress/)

It should appear here... [Wordpress About Page](http://www.imaspy.com/wordpress/about/)

Here is a snap shot of the backend widget...

[image: widget Area]

Comment: I noticed in my image that it says, "Hide on checked" but even when I select the option, "Show on checked," the widget disappears everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

I use a popular plugin for doing this type of thing: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/widget-logic/

Comment: yeah that one doesn't work either

Answer (score 0):

Try the Dynamic Widget Plugin -> http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/dynamic-widgets/